# Getting NFTs of an address in a specific collection

Tags: nft, alchemy, api, alchemy-sdk

I am using **Alchemy API** to handle **fetching NFTs** and their metadata in my platform. It has valuable methods, such as retrieving all issued NFTs of a collection or all owned NFTs of an address within a specified network.

However, I need to get **the NFTs that a specific address owns from a target NFT collection**. Is there a solution to this in Alchemy docs ( since I did not find it )? Or do I have to filter Alchemy's response by the Javascript **filter( )** method?

This is the script I am using for this purpose.

```
  const [ nfts, setNfts ] = useState(null)


  const settings = {
    apiKey: 'Alchemy API Key', 
    network: Network.MATIC_MAINNET, 
  };

  const alchemy = new Alchemy(settings);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchNfts()
  }, [])

  const fetchNfts = async () => {
    console.log("Fetching NFTs ...");
    const response = await alchemy.nft.getNftsForContract("0x220A95bdE3ffa364050FFe07b436869C08787eC8");
    setNfts(response.nfts);
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) Get all the NFTs of an address owned within a specific network by ( **You have to do the network configuration earlier** ):

```
await alchemy.nft.getNftsForOwner(address)
```

(2) Then store the response ( **It's an object** } in a state variable

(3) Within the return section of your component, try to **map over the stored array (state variable )** and filter them out based on each NFT's contract address like:

```
{
    nfts.map((nft, i) => (
        <div key={i}>
            <img src={nft.image} className="rounded" />
            <div>      
                <p>Price - {nft.price} Matic</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    ))
}
```

Each nft ( from the array we received from Alchemy and stored in a stat variable ) has some valuable properties that you can use based on the needs of your project

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with Alchemy's API, but you could definitely do this by building a subgraph for this, to index the data specific to your needs.
And then query the data from a frontend like you would from Alchemy's API.

Answer (score 0):

With this logic:

```
    const balance = await NFT.balanceOf(walletAddress);


    const getTokensId = async (recipient, index) => {
        try {
            const result = NFT.tokenOfOwnerByIndex(recipient, index);
            return result;
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error, "the error for getTokensId");
        }
    };
```

You can get the balance and the tokenId owner of a specific contract.